# Enable audible bell in gnu screen current window

Tags: bash, putty, gnu-screen, ubuntu-server

I use putty to ssh to a ubuntu bash shell, which holds irssi in a screen session.

I figure I can probably configure irssi to send system bell when certain messages show or activity happens, and I have already managed to configure putty to flash in the taskbar when it receives a bell character.

My problem is screen. I can't seem to get screen to do anything other than flash the terminal window when bell is sent from the currently active window. With `vbell on` it flashes the putty window on `echo ^G`. With `vbell off` it also flashes the putty window. When not in screen the bell is propagated properly and performs according to my putty settings. (`vbell on/off` is the same thing as pressing `ctrl+a ctrl+g`)

The core of the problem seems to be that screen uses visual bell no matter what the setting is set to. Maybe some sort of `terminfo` incompatibility between bash and screen?

How can I make screen send audible bell when it it configured to send audible bell?

Answer (score 13):

You can just push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to switch between visual and audible bell. Whenever it's in audible bell mode you should get the bell from screen.

Comment: (When in a current screensession that is)

Comment: pressing ctrla-ctrlg is the same thing as pressing ctrla+: and then typing the vbell command. That is what the vbell on/off part of my question covers. I believe you when you say that the intended behavior for screen is to propagate the audible bell with vbell off, that seems really reasonable. My problem is then that audible bell doesnt work for me in screen. [I've edited my question to provide this information]

Comment: I confirm that the answer is working as I don't have audible bell from within screen but was able to make screen send audible bell after following this advice to switch from visual to audible bell.